# Docker Desktop for Windows running at Windows10 hyper-V is not working inside Oracle Virtualbox 6

Tags: docker, virtualbox, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

I'd like to run Docker desktop for Windows on a Windows10x64 PRO VM which is inside the Oracle Virtualbox and my hyper-V feature is enabled. But I got the following error message.

```
[12:15:10.393][Linux ][Error ] Failed to start: Unable to start: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 08DABA13-9D3D-4119-9DEA-2CEFA467FA03)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 08DABA13-9D3D-4119-9DEA-2CEFA467FA03).
at Start-MobyLinuxVM, : line 296
at , : line 412. Let's retry
```

**Information**

- Windows Version: 10x64 Pro
- Docker Desktop Version: 2.0.0.3
- Oracle Virtualbox 6.0.8

**Expected behavior**

- MobyLinux VM is running on Windows10 PRO HyperV, and Docker Desktop for Windows must be started.

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**

1. Install Oracle Virtualbox 6.0.8
2. Provisioning a Windows10x64 Pro VM
3. Enable HyperV features
4. Install Docker Desktop for Windows

Comment: Just to make things clear, when you say "hyper-V feature is enabled", what do you mean exactly ? You are deploying a VM you got with hyper-v enabled inside windows ? You enabled hyper-v for the virtual processor of the vm in VirtualBox (see for your vm settings > system > acceleration > enable VT-x/AMD-V) ? Both ?

Comment: Yes, I’ve enabled them in Virtualbox